# How does this script scrape HTML from other sites using AJAX without requiring a CORS header on those sites?

Tags: php, ajax, security, curl, cors

Script in Question: http://samples.geekality.net/image-fetcher/

You can click "view source" at the bottom to pull up the exact PHP and Javascript being used.

I used part of this script to extract images on a site of mine from another on separate domains and servers. I had to go to the one being scraped and add a CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to allow my specific domain to do the AJAX $.post and actually receive data.

The script above does not require any site to have the CORS header for security. As far as I can tell I'm doing nothing different.

I have an HTML form then I'm grabbing the field data with jQuery and doing a $.post where the action is a PHP file that uses DomDocument to grab the HTML. The PHP then sorts through the data and echoes a JSON object. Then the jQuery sorts it all out and displays it on the page. Same thing they're doing.

I can't see how they're getting around the need for a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the site they're grabbing images from?

Thanks for your time and energy in this!

Comment: When you submit the form with the url it send request to http://samples.geekality.net/image-fetcher/scan.php. may be they are using cors bypassing on server side. You can do the same with jquery using cors anywhere without "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the combination of curl options in /image_finder.class.php

Specifically, the follow location, as far as I can tell.

curl_setopt_array($request, array
(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,

```
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
                    
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',

                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            ));
```